# Navigation Header Display/Initialized Wrong

Tags: android, android-xml, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I'm trying to properly display some user information in a `NavigationDrawer` header, but for some reason some of the properties are getting displayed twice in the header ("some email or other information" and the image on top). Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong and need to fix. Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of the `NavigationDrawer` header:
[image: NavigationDrawer header]

Here is the XML for the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/userImage"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Some user"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some email or other information" />
```

And here is the part of the java code that initializes the `NaviationDrawer`, loads the image, etc...:

```
main method:
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); //gets drawer button
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( //intializes toggle for navigationdrawer
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle); //sets toggle for navigationdrawer

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); //initializes list of items in navigationdrawer
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); //sets listener for items in navigationdrawer
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true); //sets "Map" as checked
    loadNavigationDrawerInfo(navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main));
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    drawer.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            Log.d("TAG", "hasFocus" + hasFocus);
        }
    });

   public void loadNavigationDrawerInfo(View headerlayout) {
        Map config = new HashMap();
        config.put("cloud_name", "some cloud name");
        config.put("api_key", "some api key");
        config.put("api_secret", "some api secret api secret");
        Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);    

        new DownloadImageTask((CircleImageView) headerlayout.findViewById(R.id.userImage)).execute("some valid URL with a jpg");
}

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        CircleImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(CircleImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            Log.d("TAG", "Done loading image");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes when you both using :

`navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);`

and `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"` in your xml. Try to disable one of them.

If you want to programmatically change email, photo use `Java` code, if you have stable header view just use `Xml` code.

Comment: Perfect! I removed the app:headerLayout in the XML and that solved the problem. Thanks!